# ADB2C Custom login page is causing the error message "server_error"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to create a custom login page that is hosted in my MVC Web App however the request is being redirected to my default error page with the message

> "server_error".

What can I do to find more information about this error?

My custom login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>This is my custom login page.</h1>
      <div id="api"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Other Notes:

- My web app is based off of the [Azure AD B2C: Call an ASP.NET Web API from an ASP.NET Web App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi).
- I'm following the article [Azure Active Directory B2C: Customize the Azure AD B2C user interface (UI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization)
- I've enabled CORS [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors)

**Update:**

The problem was that I didn't enable CORS correctly in my web app. The documentation I was reading was for .NET Core vs .NET Framework I was using.

I added this to my view.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://login.microsoftonline.com");
```

P.S. @spottedmahn recommendation for preserving the log in the Chrome console clearly showed why the error was occurring.

[image]

Comment: If you have this app deployed at some public url, can you share that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're running locally, [Enable SSL in IIS Express](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/723357/Enabling-SSL-with-IIS-Express-in-Visual-Studio).  The problem could be mixed content: [HTTP & HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content).

---

Also, in your browser, enable `preserve log`; this will provide more insight into your error(s).

[image: preserve console log]

Answer (score 0):

You could enable application insights to record the error.

[Here is some documentation on how to collect logs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom)

Comment: That will help for custom policies not for custom branding like the above :)

Comment: @spottedmahn The ContentDefinition LoadUri that is being referenced by the custom login page must have a problem with it or B2C would render the page. B2C is instead raising an error and returning to the MVC application. The error will be recorded as part of the journey recorder. It can be recorded by using Application Insights or by using the UserJourneyRecorder in this Git Hub Repo https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies

Comment: Gotcha. I'm assuming @Kevin is using built-in policies, not custom policies.